# Android Mssql server with using web service

Tags: java, android, sql-server, web-services, mssql-jdbc

i have to use mssql database for an android application. I need to connect mssql server to get/post data. Also don't want to use jdbc driver. Want to use a web service. How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, your data is saved in a myslql database that lives on a server. If you want to access the data in your database You will have to write your DAO(data access) layer. This can be done by using JDBC or using an ORM(Object relation mapping) tool like Hibernate, EJB 3 or some other solutions where you just define the "model classes" and the corresponding table and the tool do the JDBC part for you.

I hope this was useful.